# Roots of local zeta function of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

For a smooth proper curve $C$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, local zeta function can be shown that
$$
Z(C,t)=\frac{P(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}
$$
with a polynomial of degree $2g$, where $g$ is the genus of $C$.
We know that $P(t)$ decomposes as $\prod (1-\omega_i t)$, where $\omega_i$ is a complex number satisfying $\lvert\omega_i\rvert=q^{1/2}$.

My question: Is there a smooth proper curve $C$ such that $\omega_i= q^{1/2}$ for some $i$?
I can prove that there is no such an elliptic curve.

Comment: I think there is such an elliptic curve (maybe you are implicitly assuming $q$ is a prime in your proof?): Take a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ for $p>3$ and base change to $\mathbb F_{p^4}$.

Comment: Oh I see. The "proof" in my mind only workes when q=p....

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you very much. Your example completely works.

Answer (score 1):

There is such a curve on $\mathbb F_5$: $y^2=x^5+4x$. The L-function of its Jacobian is on [LMFDB](https://beta.lmfdb.org/Variety/Abelian/Fq/2/5/a_ak).